# How can I fix the scroll bar to top weather than bottom of the Panel in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, size, scrollbar, panel

I have main panel container and placed my controls on it and panel size is same as my form.
I have given the the values given below through properties to Panel.

```
AutoScroll=true;
AutoScrollMargin=0,120;
AutoScrollMinSize=1024,768;
AutoSize=true;
```

but the problem is when I open the form it Scroll down the Scroll bar by default which seems very odd.
I want that when I open the form it shouldn't be scrolled down but it should be Scroll top and when I Scroll it by mouse so I should be scroll down.

Can any body help me in properties of panel, code or any suggestion to overcome on this problem.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

By setting `AutoScroll=true`, you're telling the scrollbox to scroll down automatically as text is added to it. This is useful for logs, etc. Set it to `false` instead if that's not the behaviour you want.

Comment: I set AutoScroll=false so it removed my scroll bar and I am not able to see some of my contents.